# Need help using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to go to this site:
http://www.datiopen.it/it/opendata/Mappa_delle_stazioni_ferroviarie_in_Italia
Then click on the "Tabella" tab
Then see the second page (out of 64) of the table
However I failed in the first part, I cannot make a code to click on "Tabella" tab

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

    
driver.get('http://www.datiopen.it/it/opendata/Mappa_delle_stazioni_ferroviarie_in_Italia')
element = driver.find_element_by_id("Tabella")
element.click()
```

And here is the html code that I used to search:

```
<li id="Tabella" class="Table_img ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
                <span id="span_table_img" class="span_img"></span>
            <a href="#ui-tabs-1" rel="nofollow">Tabella</a>         </li>
```

Thank all!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Wups I changed it to `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#ui-tabs-1']")` still not work. the error is: `ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add time sleep before accessing the table element.

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('Tabella').click()
```

Comment: It worked really well! Can you please tell me the logic of this?

Comment: @Mark Bils logic is that selenium is try to access element when the page is loaded but some element are still in progress that's why they are not present in DOM of page. You can use `time.sleep` or  `WebDriverWait` for them to fully load.

Answer (score 0):

To click on `Tabella` tab you need to induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and you can use  following locator.

**Link Text:**

```
driver.get("http://www.datiopen.it/it/opendata/Mappa_delle_stazioni_ferroviarie_in_Italia")    
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Tabella"))).click()
```

**XPATH**:

```
driver.get("http://www.datiopen.it/it/opendata/Mappa_delle_stazioni_ferroviarie_in_Italia")    
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Tabella']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it really necessary to use so many libraries? I mean it is quite a simple task

Comment: @MarkBils : `WebDriverWait()` is best practice when you are interacting with browser.This will help you to get around browser synchronization issue and you can get around problem like  `ElementNotInteractableException` and no such element exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with your code**

You are trying to click an element before it is available/ready to click in DOM.

**Solution**

You need to wait for the element to load and become clickable to perform any kind of action on the same element.

**Code**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.datiopen.it/it/opendata/Mappa_delle_stazioni_ferroviarie_in_Italia')


def wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(element):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, element)))

wait_for_element_to_be_clickable("Tabella")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("Tabella")
element.click()
print("executed")
```

`def wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(element):` this method will wait for any element to become clickable before proceeding. (you can increase the time based on your page loading time).